# How to delete a element from vector given a pointer to it - C++

Tags: c++, vector

If I have a vector that looks like this `{a, b, c, d, e, f}` and I have a pointer named `myPointer` and it points to element `e`, how can I delete `e` from the vector?

Here is example code of what I would like to do

```
vector<char> v = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};

char *myPointer = &v[4];

// I want to do something like this
v.erase(myPointer);

// Output
// a, b, c, d, f
```

Can this be done?

Comment: Essentially you want to convert a pointer to an iterator? `v.begin()+(myPointer-v.data())` should work. But did you really have to use pointers in the first place?

Comment: If that would work, then yes? I don't have to use the `erase` function. I just need to remove the element from the vector given a pointer to it.

Comment: Removing vector elements using pointers its the wrong way just use iterators

Comment: The above code is for an idea of what I want to accomplish. Obviously deleting with an iterator is the correct way to delete from a vector. However, my current limitations are that I only have a pointer to an element in a vector and I need to delete that element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a pointer to the first element to calculate the offset, then use that to create an iterator to pass to `std::vector::erase`.

```
auto offset = myPointer - v.data();
v.erase(v.begin() + offset);
```

This assumes `myPointer` points to an element of `v`. If not, the behaviour is undefined.

---

Working example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    int* p = &v[3];

    v.erase(v.begin() + (p - v.data()));

    for (auto i: v)
        std::cout << i << ' ';

    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

output:

> 1 2 3 5 6 7 8

Comment: I'm not familiar with vector::data(). How efficient is this approach?

Comment: @GaryJohnson O(1). `v.data()` gives you a pointer to the first element of the vector's internal data block.

Comment: `vector::data()` just returns a pointer to the allocated array

Comment: It still costs `O(n)` due to the [vector::erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/) function, but it surely is the easiest and fastest way to use here.

Comment: @GaryJohnson I mean, O(1) for finding the element to erase. The erase itself is amortized O(N), but there's no escaping that.

Comment: @J3soon Yes, I was just clarifying that :-)

Answer (score 1):

The data stored by a `vector` is contiguous, so you can convert a pointer to an iterator by: getting a pointer to the first element, doing pointer arithmetic to find the difference and then apply that to `begin`:

```
assert(v.data() <= mypointer && mypointer < v.data()+v.size());
v.erase(v.begin() + (mypointer - v.data()));
```

Comment: @MarcGlisse explain please?

Comment: @Simple ah ok, I see that now